# How do you rewrite a differential equation for an electrical circuit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't understand the following differential equation which has the argument t in the numerator as well as in the denominator:

$$
R*C*(dv_2(t)/dt)+v_2(t)=v_1(t)
$$

How do you rewrite it to the form underneath so that I can find the general solution?
$$
y'+P(t)*y(t)=Q(t)
$$
It has to satisfy $$t\geq0$$
R and C are meant to hold values for resistance and capacitance.

Comment: If you mean $\;"dt"\;$ that's just a pretty standard, elementary part of the notation for derivative with respect to $\;t\;$ , so $\;\frac{dv_2(t)}{dt}\;$ is just $\;v_2'(t)\;$ , the derivative of $\;v_2\;$ wrt $\;t\;$ ...If you don't know this then this exercise may be not fit for you, yet.

Comment: You do understand that $y'$ means $dy/dt$, don’t you?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't say $dy$ in the numerator, which confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

Your unknown function is not called $y(x)$ but $v_2(t)$. Your equation for $v_2(t)$ is
$$
v_2'+\frac{1}{RC}v_2=\frac{1}{RC}v_1(t).
$$